# Opening a Remote Shell Renames Buffer Open to \*shell\*

Tags: buffers, tramp, shell

here is a simple elisp program for opening a shell in a named buffer:

```
(defun shell-make (dir buffer-name)
  (let* ((default-directory dir)
         (buffer (get-buffer-create buffer-name)))
  (set-buffer buffer)
  (shell buffer)))
```

Here is an example of a command that will open in shell in a buffer named `shell~`

```
 (defun shell~ () (interactive) (shell-make "~" "shell~"))
```

It works fine.  `M-x shell~`  will open a new shell and the buffer name will be `shell~`.

Now using Tramp to get a local shell named `shell-root`:

```
(defun shell-root ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-make "/sudo::/root" "shell-root")`)
```

That also works.

Now using Tramp to get a remote shell:

```
(defun shell-remote ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-make "/ssh:user@domain.com:~" "shell-remote"))
```

This does not work.  The buffer will always be called `*shell*`.   Even worse, once one shell is named `*shell*`  all other remote shell calls simply open that buffer, and do not make new shells.

How can this be code be adjusted so that Tramp does not rename the buffer for remote shells to `*shell*`?

---

Here are the *messages* from a failure, shell-root above which opened a buffer named *shell*:

```
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.13) of 2019-12-10
Tramp: Opening connection for user@host.com using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh -l user  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none host.com’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on ‘host.com’
Tramp: Opening connection for user@host.com using ssh...done
Tramp: Opening connection for user@host.com using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh -q -l user  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none host.com’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on ‘host.com’
Tramp: Opening connection for user@host.com using ssh...done
```

[image: showing the *shell*]

Comment: Which Emacs version do you use? I've tried Emacs 26.3, and all three commands `shell~`, `shell-root` and `shell-remote` work as expected. Note, that there is a typo in your definition of `shell-root`.

Comment: also using 26.3.  I think there is a timing race involved.  I thought I saw it work once also.  Anyway, it is consistently not working right now.

Comment: Michael, just added to the bottom of the post the \*messages\* which includes version info, and a screen shot, that resulted from using 'shell-remote'.

Comment: Well, the messages from the *Messages* buffer are not sufficient for debugging. If you want to get it analyzed in more detail, pls send a mail the the `tramp-deverl@gnu.org` ML. Ahh, and before I forget: does it happen also when you call `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Michael,    I only program emacs once in a while, and had suspected I had programmed the function incorrectly.  it did not do it with emacs -Q.  My bad.  Long long ago I made another function with the same name as one involved here, buried deep in the bowels of .emacs.  Thanks.  I wonder if I should delete this question.  It is not likely to be helpful to someone else.

Comment: No reason to delete, people will see the comments. I'm happy there's no Tramp error :-)